# How can I dynamically create an unordered list of comma-separated items entered into a field?

Tags: angularjs

If I provide an input like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="entries" placeholder="Type several entries">
```

When users type in a string like "Book, magazine, newspaper", **how can I dynamically split each comma-separated entry into an unordered list item?**  I guess this works with `ng-list` but I haven't been able to get it working.

I tried like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries">
  <ul ngModel="entries">{{entries}}</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to consider `ng-list`.  The usage is simply:

```
 <input ng-list ng-model="entries" placeholder="Type several entries">

 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="e in entries">
     {{e}}
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Adapted from the [api documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList), here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/LBZgQD5xwOS9fORXjOt5?p=preview

Comment: learn something new everyday! Didn't know about the ng-list directive - definitely a lot cleaner than using the split function.